# Forzar formato de Fecha en datagridview

Tags: c#

Buenas tardes: Tengo un `Dgv` con una celda que contiene la Fecha, En el Load del Formulario hago lo siguiente:

```
dgvContratoRenov.Columns[14].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "d";
```

Al ejecutar el Proyecto, la Fecha aparece bien `(Ej: 05/04/2017)`.
Mi problema es que a la hora que la modifico no respeta los "/" y tengo que escribir la fecha completa. La idea es que funcione como si fuera un `MaskedTextbox`, es decir, **`que después de ingresar el día se salte a la posición del mes y luego del año.`**

Es posible?
Gracias

Comment: Considera controlar el evento TextChanged de la celda, si es que tiene.

Comment: lo que se debe de hacer es que la columna sea de tipo DateTime

Answer (score 5):

Yo he probado con la [libreria](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26005/DataGridViewColumn-Hosting-MaskedTextBox) y desde el mismo diseñador del winform puedes seleccionar el nuevo tipo `DataGridViewMaskedTextColumn`

En el fichero Designer.cs quedaría asi:

```
//Declaración
private JThomas.Controls.DataGridViewMaskedTextColumn Fecha; //Declaración de la columna

...

private void InitializeComponent()
{
  //...
  this.Fecha = new JThomas.Controls.DataGridViewMaskedTextColumn();

  //...
  this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
            this.Fecha});

   // 
   // Fecha
   // 
   dataGridViewCellStyle1.Format = "d";
   this.Fecha.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;
   this.Fecha.HeaderText = "Fecha";
   this.Fecha.Mask = "00/00/0000";
   this.Fecha.Name = "Fecha";
   this.Fecha.Resizable = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;

 //...
}
```

No se si es tarde pero espero que le pueda servir a alguien. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo creo que esto te pueda ayudar pon este código:

```
 Convert.ToDateTime(DtSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FInicioEmpresa"].ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: Hola Pierro: En qué parte pongo esto? Gracias

Comment: Piero, explica mejor como funciona tu respuesta para que @MarioEscudero pueda entenderla y saber cómo incluirlo

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza

```
dgvContratoRenov.Columns[14].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
```

Ya sea al momento de inicializar tu DataGridView o mediante el diseñador.

Comment: Al usar el formato `"d"` es lo mismo que use `"dd/MM/yyyy"`, debido a que su configuración regional tiene ese formato (lo indica en la pregunta). El problema que tiene es al momento de modificar, no considera dicho formato.